# 3 tables interact with eachother together but patient id coming back nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i have three models that associate with each other. I have patients, providers, and lists. patients can have many providers and vice versa. List is the middle man. patients can add providers to list which works perfect and it displays all the providers on the list_id. However on the provider side when i try to render to all the providers patients. I get a error saying "Couldn't find Patient with "id"=
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s092R.png)

```
class ProvidersController < ApplicationController
def patient_access
        @provider = current_user.provider
        @active_patients = @provider.lists.where(soft_delete: false)
        render "providers/patient_access"
    end
end

<!-- Here is the patients controller which everything works fine on the patients side of the app as far as displaying all providers that belongs to that patient -->

class PatientsController < ApplicationController
def provider_access
        flash[:modal] = true
        @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
        @active_providers = @patient.lists.where(soft_delete: false)

    end
end
```

<-- Here is my patient_access.html.erb file -->

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/side_menu' %>
<div class="container-main">
    <br/>
<div class="content-container your-sites">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="icon-circle"><div class="icon"><%= image_tag "my-providers-2x.png" %></div></div>
            <div class="title">Your Patients</div>
        </div><!--header-->
        <div class="body">
            <div class="body">
            <% if @active_patients.count > 0 %>
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Patient Name</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <% @active_patients.each do |list| %>
                      <tr>
                        <td><%= list.patient.role.user.first_name %> <%= list.patient.role.user.last_name %></td>
                        <td>
                            <%= link_to patients_path(patient_id) %>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <% end %>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            <% else %>
                <div class="no-records">
                    <%= image_tag "icon-no-records", class: "image" %>
                    <div class="text">You have no patients.</div>
                </div><!--no-records-->
            <% end %>
        </div><!--body-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect that `@patient = Patient.find_by_id(params[:id])` is the problem, as its in the ProvidersController, so I would assume that `params[:id]` would be the id of the provider. If this is the case then you might get this error, as there it might be provider id = 100 and there might not be a Patient with id = 100. However, I'm also curious why you even have `@patient = Patient.find_by_id(params[:id])` in there, it doesn't look to be used in your partial

Comment: well i have @patient = Patient.find_by_in(params[:id]) becuase im trying to render all the patient first and last names in the view

Comment: I notice that you edited out the `@patient = Patient.find_by_id(params[:id])`, are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

In the view you have a link: `<%= link_to patients_path(id: provider.id) %>`
and in the controller `@patient = Patient.find_by_id(params[:id])` - which is literally equal to `@patient = Patient.find_by_id(provider.id)` and of course rails can't find such a record.

you should pass `patient_id` to this action if you want to find some specific patient.